# How do I replace the values of one column with the values of another column in the same table

Tags: sql

Can anyone please explain how to replace the values of one column with the values of another column in the same table (in sql). Don't we have a Replace All in SQL like we have in foxpro database?

Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE YourTable SET ColA = ColB`. If that isn't what you need then please give more details (table structure, example data, before and after results)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a regular update statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable Set Column1 = Column2
```